# How can I disable read receipts in Windows 8 mail client (connected to Exchange)?

Tags: email, windows-8-preview, exchange, office365

I have the Windows 8 built-in mail client connected to my Exchange account (hosted Office365). By default it silently sends read receipts (at least to mail sent from my domain). My Outlook 2010 (Win7) client is configured to never send read receipts (and it doesn't), so it is definitely a client issue and not something configured in the Exchange server.

How can I turn off read receipts so Windows 8 mail client will *never* send them?